# Gets an error when reauthenticating to twitter after cancelling authorization on twitter using hybridauth

Tags: php, twitter, hybridauth

This is the scenario:

1. Request for authentication.
2. Twitter asks for authorization
3. Hit `Cancel` then hit `Return to insert_app_name_here`
4. Request for authentication again.
5. You get this, `Authentication failed! Twitter returned an invalid oauth verifier.`
6. Request for authentication again.
7. Twitter is normal now and asks for authorization.

I don't know if this is a bug in `HybridAuth` but is there another way I can get around this error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to usually happen if you dont clear out the session. Hybrid caches stuff agressively, but I dont think its particularly vigilant about sanity checking its cache. So if you end up with half finished auth, it just loses its cool and crashes. It also seems to be fairly dependent on the provider as far as I can tell. I never have problems with facebook, but google+ auth seems to explode if you even look at it the wrong way.

In summary, flush your session , using whatever your framework of choice provides for this.